# Как во время отправки ajax запроса сделать всплывающее на 5 сек модальное окно?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form

Есть типичная форма отправки сообщения, которая отправляет данные на `php` страницу c помощью `ajax` с которой идет перенаправление обратно, и при этом всплывает модальное окно с благодарностью.

Как сделать так, чтобы запрос сработал (возврат на страницу за это время произошел), а модальное окно при этом повисело 5 секунд и потом исчезло, а не как сейчас появляется только на мгновение.

**Важно!** Запрос за это время должен сработать, сделать настройку в `ajax` на 5 сек не подойдет, но и `setTimeout` меня в данном случае не выручает.

```js
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(e) {
  $('#box_modal').css('display', 'block');
  $('#box_modal').animate({
    'opacity': 1
  }, 500);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    success: function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#box_modal').css('opacity', 0);
        $('#box_modal').css('display', 'none');
      }, 5000);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#box_modal {
  background-color: blue;
  color: red;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm" method="post" action="mail.php">
  <input type="text" value="Hello there">
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>

<div id="box_modal" style="display:none;">
  Thank you!
</div>
```

Comment: в ajax есть параметр [beforeSend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), который принимает функцию. В ней напишите код для вызова модалки. Еще вам понадобится [setTimeout](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval)

Comment: @Виталий Шебаниц а `setTimout` где прописывать - там же, в `beforeSend` или в `success`

Comment: прописывать нужно там, где хотите чтобы задержка была